# Tensorboard not showing GPU Device

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm using TensorFlow version 1.13.
I trained 2 different models using GPU:

- NVIDIA V100: Adanet
- NVIDIA K80: MNIST

In first Adanet model, during training I can see TF is seeing GPU:

```
I  master-replica-0 Starting evaluation at 2019-03-17T04:55:12Z master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Graph was finalized. master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Adding visible gpu devices: 0 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0      0  master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 0:   N  master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14927 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 7.0) master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Restoring parameters from gs://dpe-sandbox/adanet/trial1/model.ckpt-36000 master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Running local_init_op. master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 Done running local_init_op. master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 index, memory.used [MiB], memory.total [MiB], utilization.gpu [%], power.draw [W], power.limit [W] master-replica-0 
I  master-replica-0 0, 15511 MiB, 16130 MiB, 82 %, 218.22 W, 300.00 W master-replica-0
```

- Adanet Model [here](https://github.com/sararob/adanet-ml-engine/tree/master/)
- MNIST Model [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/tree/master/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/mlengine)

In TensorBoard: Under Graphs -> Device -> I don't see my GPU listed.

[image]

**Note**: I'm using GCP Cloud ML Engine to allocate the GPUs

XLA Cluster, Compute Time, Memory are grayed out.

Do I need to add any specific parameter to my TensorFlow code?